# How do I float an image in the middle of a header and content section?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a header and content section. I styled the header to a gradient and to be in a trapezoid shape. I want to have an image (leaf.png) be in the middle of these two divs while floating in front of them. However, my header overrides the image for some reason. Here is a picture of what I want to have:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nih2l.jpg)
But this is what happens instead:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywRiM.jpg)
I don't know what is happening or how to fix it. I want the end result to look like the header at [stripe.com.](http://stripe.com)Here is my code right now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<style>
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, black);
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
}

header h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <img src="leaf.png" style="float:right" />
  <div class="header__bg"></div>
<h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>
<section>

  <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, here is a picture of the leaf: https://ibb.co/dFqdw9
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the image of the leaf

Comment: Yes. https://ibb.co/dFqdw9

Comment: so now we have the picture you can edit your code to use the snippet and make it a runnable code and it will be easier for us to help

Comment: Code pen: https://codepen.io/BlueWater134/pen/jeMejP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        header {
            position: relative;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .header__bg {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: linear-gradient(blue, black);
            transform: skewY(-6deg);
            transform-origin: top left;
        }
        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 100px 0;
            font: 44px "Arial";
        }
        img {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        header h1 {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="leaf.png" style="float:right"/>
        <div class="header__bg"></div>
        <h1>Header Content</h1>
    </header>
    <section>

        <h1>Section Content</h1>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the image of the webpage after you've made the suggested edits?

Comment: That's great you're almost there, now remove position property from header h1, check the new edit.

Comment: Try playing around with positioning, set the position of header h1 to absolute. [IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/2aiilhg.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

You can update the inline styles like so :

```
<header>
  <div class="header__bg"></div>
  <div>
        <img src="leaf.png" style="right: 0; position: fixed; z-index: 2;" />
   </div>
<h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: can you setup a codepen, that way I can better diagnose and update my answer

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer and after some local tests.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried this before with multiple pngs with transparent backgrounds, and I got the same result. Here is kinda what I want: stripe.com

Comment: Yes you are correct it does have transparency.  I have updated my answer.  You need to update your css like what is reflected above.  That way the leaf only will show above your elements and to the right

Comment: I made one last edit.  Now that you are using z-index, you can keep the leaf img tag in the body of the header.